# PHP prevent including same file twice

Tags: php, session, if-statement, include, isset

Hi I have following files:
login.php, index.php, header.php, footer.php, restrictaccess.php

restrictaccess.php has following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != ''))
if (!(isset($_SESSION['access']) && $_SESSION['access'] != '')) 
{
header ("Location: login.php");
exit();
}


if($_SESSION['access']=="2" ) {
     echo 'You are logged on as Manager';

}
if($_SESSION['access']=="1" ) {
     echo 'You are logged on as Restricted user';
}
?>
```

restrictaccess.php, header.php and footer.php is included on every page accept login.php.
Both header and footer also includes restrictaccess.php; will this cause any problem ? Is there anyway so that such includes will only be loaded once ?

Currently when someone logon the message "You are loged on as Manager/Restricted user" is displayed thrice.

Your help will be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Use [`include_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)

Comment: Try using `include_once`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `require_once()` to include your file. This method checks wether the file was already included.

[PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.require-once.php)

Answer (score 1):

**UGLY** method

Use `require_once` or `include_once` for restrictaccess.php

**Better** method

Change restrictaccess.php to only:

```
<?php
if (!(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != ''))
if (!(isset($_SESSION['access']) && $_SESSION['access'] != '')) 
{
  header ("Location: login.php");
  exit();
}
?>
```

Then use `session_start()` at the top of every client page (the pages that user can browse to like index.php).
Use the code about "You are logged-in as ..." only in the header.php (or wherever it make sense to display.

**UPDATE**

You can include the above restrictaccess.php anywhere in you files **BUT** you have to make sure that there is no data sent to the client prior to the `header ("Location: login.php");` bit (i.e. if you have any `echo`, `print_r` or `var_dump`... before the `header ("Location: login.php");` then PHP will generate an error)

Comment: along with session_start() ; do I also include restrictaccess.php on all the pages ?

Comment: Almost (see my edit above), you can add it to any page you want to guarantee an authorized access. If you keep it as in my example, it is safe to include multiple time because no function/class is declared, and the only outcome is a redirection.